# Losing connection to Kafka. What happens?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

A jobmanager and taskmanager are running on a single VM. Also Kafka runs on the same server.

I have 10 tasks, all read from different kafka topics , process messages and write back to Kafka.
Sometimes I find my task manager is down and nothing is working. I tried to figure out the problem by checking the logs and I believe it is a problem with Kafka connection. (Or maybe a network problem?. But everything is on a single server.)

What I want to ask is, if for a short period I lose connection to Kafka what happens. Why tasks are failing and most importantly why task manager crushes?

Some logs:

```
2022-11-26 23:35:15,626 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Producer clientId=producer-15] Disconnecting from node 0 due to request timeout.
2022-11-26 23:35:15,626 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Producer clientId=producer-8] Disconnecting from node 0 due to request timeout.
2022-11-26 23:35:15,626 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Consumer clientId=cpualgosgroup1-1, groupId=cpualgosgroup1] Disconnecting from node 0 due to request timeout.
2022-11-26 23:35:15,692 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Consumer clientId=telefilter1-0, groupId=telefilter1] Cancelled in-flight FETCH request with correlation id 3630156 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 61648ms, elapsed time since send: 61648ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2022-11-26 23:35:15,702 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Producer clientId=producer-15] Cancelled in-flight PRODUCE request with correlation id 2159429 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 51069ms, elapsed time since send: 51069ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2022-11-26 23:35:15,702 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Consumer clientId=cpualgosgroup1-1, groupId=cpualgosgroup1] Cancelled in-flight FETCH request with correlation id 2344708 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 51184ms, elapsed time since send: 51184ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2022-11-26 23:35:15,702 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Producer clientId=producer-15] Cancelled in-flight PRODUCE request with correlation id 2159430 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 51069ms, elapsed time since send: 51069ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2022-11-26 23:35:15,842 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender           [] - [Producer clientId=producer-15] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition tele.alerts.cpu-4 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now
2022-11-26 23:35:15,842 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender           [] - [Producer clientId=producer-8] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition tele.alerts.cpu-6 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now
2
```

and then

```
2022-11-26 23:35:56,673 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - CPUTemperatureAnalysisAlgorithm -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (1/1)#0 (619139347a459b6de22089ff34edff39_d0ae1ab03e621ff140fb6b0b0a2932f9_0_0) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Disconnect from JobManager responsible for 8d57994a59ab86ea9ee48076e80a7c7f.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor.disconnectJobManagerConnection(TaskExecutor.java:1702)
        ...
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
        Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The heartbeat of JobManager with id 99d52303d7e24496ae661ddea2b6a372 timed out.

2022-11-26 23:35:56,682 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Triggering cancellation of task code CPUTemperatureAnalysisAlgorithm -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (1/1)#0 (619139347a459b6de22089ff34edff39_d0ae1ab03e621ff140fb6b0b0a2932f9_0_0).
2022-11-26 23:35:57,199 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Attempting to fail task externally TemperatureAnalysis -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (1/1)#0 (619139347a459b6de22089ff34edff39_15071110d0eea9f1c7f3d75503ff58eb_0_0).
2022-11-26 23:35:57,202 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - TemperatureAnalysis -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (1/1)#0 (619139347a459b6de22089ff34edff39_15071110d0eea9f1c7f3d75503ff58eb_0_0) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Disconnect from JobManager responsible for 8d57994a59ab86ea9ee48076e80a7c7f.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor.disconnectJobManagerConnection(TaskExecutor.java:1702)
```

Why taskexecutor loses connection to JobManager?

If I dont care any data lost, how should I configure Kafka clients and flink recovery. I just want Kafka Client not to die. Especially I dont want my tasks or task managers to crush. If I lose connection, is it possible to configure Flink to just for wait? If we can`t read, wait and if we can't write back to Kafka, just wait?

Comment: Ideally, Kafka should run on separate machine from Flink

Comment: Yes but as it is not possible at the moment, I just doubled CPU/Memory. But still taskmanager is crushing.

Comment: Is kafka broker actually healthy? Local connections should never lose connection unless the server itself stopped

Comment: yes, it seems it is working fine. I just find the log below on Flink side. Maybe it is a throughput issue. Kafka should process 70K/sec messages in 10 different topics and it is running on a single SSD.

Comment: org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter$WriterCallback.throwException(KafkaWriter.java:436) ~[?:?]
        at 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.BufferExhaustedException: 
Failed to allocate 16384 bytes within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms. 
Total memory: 33554432 bytes. 
Available memory: 0 bytes. Poolable size: 16384 bytes

Comment: `Available memory: 0 bytes` seems like an issue. That error comes from Kafka producer config `batch.size`, which defaults to `16384 bytes`... So, that means you are trying to make Flink send too many requests without flushing the Kafka producer buffer

Comment: But flink backpressure mechanism should manage it right? My input and output are Kafka. So If I cant write to Kafka, flink  shouldnt read the next input  message ? For now, should I increase kafka buffer? `batch.size`  Still I dont understand why task manager crushes?

Comment: I've not used Flink, so I'm not sure. Maybe it's a bug, but if the Kafka buffer is backed up, then Flink will need to maintain its own buffer(s) for data you're trying to send. Then if those fill up, you'd eventually end up with OOM and crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The heartbeat of JobManager with id 99d52303d7e24496ae661ddea2b6a372 timed out.

Sounds like the server is somewhat overloaded. But you could try increasing the [heartbeat timeout](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/config/#heartbeat-timeout).

Comment: Thanks,The workload on the server is very high. I will increase heartbeat timeout but still I`d like to know what happens if Kafka goes down or flink losts connection to Kafka. I beleive this might not be a timeout problem. I really lose taskmanagers somehow. if a taskmanager cant connect to jobmanager, does it shut down?

Comment: Hi David, I increased the heartbeat, something like 300000 but still task manager is crushing. Both job manager and task manager are running on the same server. Kafka is also on the same server  . It would be appreciated if you could shed some light.